# Maximum z-index value for chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

in Chrome when i set z-index to 2147483647 it changes to 1e+06.. what is the maximum possible value for chrome?

Answer (score 6):

> > .css('z-index', '99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999').css('z-index')

becomes `1e+308`. If you add another digit after it becomes "inf".

Answer (score 2):

It is 2147483647 (0x7fffffff).

According to the source code of WebKit, the "zIndex" has been an "int" value since the first commit: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/d869b93fe74f4d6cb2dd6f6c3e9bf9daee39ba19/third_party/WebKit/WebCore/khtml/rendering/render_style.h#828 .

And tests on Chrome 35 (32-bit), 45 (64-bit), 74 (64-bit) (for Windows) confirm it.

I also tested Firefox 66 and max of zIndex is also 2147483647 there.

Notes:

- WebKit: Chrome (Chromium) once used it to render web pages and some years ago it's renamed into "blink" and integrated into Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

Being a 32-bit browser, you found the highest value.

2147483648 = 2^31